# return only last inserted parent id on childs table of multiple duplicate parents ids

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get values of last inserted parents id on childs table then join the
grandparents table to get the property and their totals.

Here is my table structure:

```
parents
+------------
|pid | item |
+----+------+
| 1  | ite1 |
| 2  | ite2 |
+-----------+

childs
+-------------+
| cid  | pid  |
+------+------+
| 1    | 1    | -- not
| 2    | 1    | ---- row to be selected(last inserted to join grandparents)
| 3    | 2    | -- not 
| 4    | 2    | ---- row to be selected(last inserted to join grandparents)
+-------------+

grandparents
+----------------------+
| gid | cid | property |
+-----+-----+----------+
| 1   | 1   | 1200     |
| 2   | 1   | 1500     |
| 3   | 2   | 101      |
| 4   | 2   | 303      |
| 5   | 3   | 600      |
| 6   | 3   | 10       |
| 7   | 4   | 335      |
| 8   | 4   | 250      |
+----------------------+
```

results

```
+----------------------------+
| item   | cid  |  property  |
+--------+------+------------+
| ite1   | 2    | 101        |
| ite1   | 2    | 303        |
| ite1   | 4    | 335        |
| ite1   | 4    | 250        |
+----------------------------+

Total property results : sum(101 + 303 +335 + 250) =   989
```

I tried this query but return/ includes the rows( with not as shown on  childs ) which cause
the total of whole grandparents table

```
query:

SELECT g.property from grandparents g
join childs c on g.cid = c.cid
join parents p on c.pid = p.pid
where c.pid in (select DISTINCT pid from childs) and c.pid = 1
```

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: Hello, I'm using  mysqlnd 7.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a subquery to get `MAX(cid)` then do `JOIN` by subquery's `cid`

```
SELECT g.property 
from grandparents g
join (
    SELECT pid ,MAX(cid) cid
    FROM childs 
    GROUP BY pid  
) c on g.cid = c.cid
join parents p on c.pid = p.pid
```